# Get results of a column that aren't NULL in array of objects in Angular 12

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Angular 12 project and I want to retrieve all results in artisticBehaviour (except those who are `null` or same e.g. Actor, Actor) column in Users table.

Here is the function that I call to get all users from the Users table.

```typescript
allArtistsSet() {
  this.userData.allArtists(this.offset).pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      if (data.success) {
        this.allArtists = data.artistsFeed;
        this.creativenessArtists = this.allArtists.filter((data) => 
          data.artisticBehaviour != null);
      }
    })
  ).subscribe()
}
```

```html
<select style="background-color: #333;color: whitesmoke;padding: 5px;font-size: small; border-radius: 5px;width: 110px;">
    <option disabled>Creative Behaviour</option>
    <option>Creativeness</option>
    <option *ngFor="let creative of creativenessArtists" value="{{creative}}">{{creative}}</option>
</select>
```

This returns

```
[object Object]
[object Object]
```

Here is the structure of returned array. I want to get only artisticBevaiour values but not the ones that are `null`.

```
{success: true, artistsFeed: [,…]}
artistsFeed: [,…]
0: 
artisticBehaviour: null
username: "RickChavez"

1: 
artisticBehaviour: "Writer"
username: "babarshahb05"

2: 
artisticBehaviour: "Actor"
username: shakir"

3: {friend_id: "587", friend_two: "1102", friend_one: "1122", uid: "1102", username: "mellita863",…}
.....
```

In this case, I want to get "Actor" and "Writer" but not `null`.

Comment: It looks like Angular is calling the default [`Object#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) when attempting to resolve the [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation) `{{creative}}`. You will need to provide a custom `toString()` method on the type in the `creativenessArtists` array, change your interpolation to use a field on the type (`{{creative.name}}` or similar), or provide Angular with a component capable of rendering your desired HTML from the type.

Comment: Could you please post your type definition for the `creativenessArtists` or clarify your problem?

Comment: i did D M i hope it clarifies for you

Comment: Sure, so you want the `artisticBehavior` field (not the whole object). Your template interpolation should be `{{creative.artisticBehavior}}`.

Comment: i did, it returns just two  <option>. and if i refresh the page it gets different two and so on... and it included null entries